# Popen / Wait - Wait never finishes

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

```
import sys
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

# Transfer Database
print ('Transferring from ' + mysql_source_database)
mysql = Popen(f"mysql -h {mysql_dest_host} -P 3306 -u {mysql_dest_username} -p{mysql_dest_pw} {mysql_dest_database}".split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
dbnamerewrite = Popen(f"sed s/{mysql_source_database}/{mysql_dest_database}/g".split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=mysql.stdin)
mysqldump = Popen(f"mysqldump --set-gtid-purged=OFF --column-statistics=0 -h {mysql_source_host} -P 3306 -u {mysql_source_username} -p{mysql_source_pw} {mysql_source_database}".split(), stdout=dbnamerewrite.stdin)
mysql_stdout = mysql.communicate()[0]
mysqldump.wait()
```

The above code does what I want it to but never stops waiting. Does anyone know how to fix the wait. If I ctrl-c it after the SQL work has finished this is the given error:

```
^CERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3829: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    mysql_stdout = mysql.communicate()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1028, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1868, in _communicate
    ready = selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/selectors.py", line 415, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: FWIW, I've always thought is simpler to write a list of argument strings instead of splitting a formatted string. It avoids the need for 90% of formatting, and you don't need special handling when you quote stuff. So the first arg-set would be `['mysql', '-h', mysql_dest_host, '-P', '3306', '-u', mysql_dest_username, f'-p{mysql_dest_pw}', mysql_dest_database]`. Only one f-string, less chance of ambiguity, and you can reuse common bits for the other calls too.

Comment: Was able to reproduce with a pipe of `ls | grep ... | grep ...`, so will investigate

Comment: Thanks, the wait works if I do not have dbnamerewrite in the chain.

Comment: Also seems to work if you just drop the wait. Communicate does that for you implicitly anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing is that you should drop the explicit call to `mysqldump.wait()`. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> **Note:** This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) when using pipes to avoid that.

[`mysql.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) is sufficient in this case, because it will not receive an EOF until all the elements up the pipeline send one. So `mysql.communicate()` returning directly implies that the other two processes are done.

Another problem is that with the ordering of processes that you have, you will have to call `communicate` on all of them in reverse order to get data flowing through the pipeline. One solution is to do just that:

```
db_param = ['-h', mysql_dest_host, '-P', '3306', '-u', mysql_dest_username, f'p{mysql_dest_pw}', mysql_dest_database]

mysql = Popen(['mysql'] + db_param,
              stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
dbnamerewrite = Popen(['sed', f's/{mysql_source_database}/{mysql_dest_database}/g'],
                      stdin=PIPE, stdout=mysql.stdin)
mysqldump = Popen(['mysqldump', '--set-gtid-purged=OFF', '--column-statistics=0'] + db_param,
                  stdout=dbnamerewrite.stdin)

mysqldump.communicate()
dbnamerewrite.communicate()
mysql_stdout = mysql.communicate()[0]
```

The other alternative is to set up your pipe in the opposite order, in which case you only need to `communicate` with the last process:

```
db_param = ['-h', mysql_dest_host, '-P', '3306', '-u', mysql_dest_username, f'p{mysql_dest_pw}', mysql_dest_database]

mysqldump = Popen(['mysqldump', '--set-gtid-purged=OFF', '--column-statistics=0'] + db_param,
                  stdout=PIPE)
dbnamerewrite = Popen(['sed', f's/{mysql_source_database}/{mysql_dest_database}/g'],
                      stdin=mysqldump.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
mysql = Popen(['mysql'] + db_param, stdin=dbnamerewrite.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

mysql_stdout = mysql.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: You are right that removing the wait was part of the solution but I also had to run communicate on the middle subprocess:
dbnamerewrite_stdout = dbnamerewrite.communicate()[0]

Comment: @Krobar. I was just coming to the same conclusion. Will figure out why momentarily.

Comment: @Krobar. Hopefully my update has cleared some stuff up